# Error de la dependencia resolve a la hora de instalar el CLI de AngularJS

Tags: nodejs, angular

Estoy intentando instalar el CLI de AngularJs a través de npm, pero al momento de ejecutar el `npm i -g angular/cli` me sale el siguiente error:

> npm ERR! code No matching version found for resolve@1.22.1.

> npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or your dependencies are requesting

> npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

He revisado mi package.json y la dependencia `resolve` no aparece, por lo que la he instalado y demás pero sigue saliendo el mismo error.

Comment: intenta escribirlo de forma directa o borra el cache y vuelve a instalar las dependecias

Comment: Solo para aclarar, tu proyecto es AngularJS? Es muy diferente de Angular2+, que es al que actualmente se le da soporte, y lo que estás instalando es Angular2+